# Linq: X objects in a row

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I need help with a linq query that will return true if the list contains x objects in a row when the list is ordered by date.

so like this:

```
myList.InARow(x => x.Correct, 3)
```

would return true if there are 3 in a row with the property correct == true.

Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built into linq that handles this case easily.  But it is a relatively simple matter to create your own extension method.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public IEnumerable<T> InARow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
                                    Predicate<T> filter, int length) {
        int run = 0;
        foreach (T element in list) {
            if (filter(element)) {
                if (++run >= length) return true;
            } 
            else {
                run = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bunch of good answers. This one will be the easiest for future developers to read, so i'm going to go with this one.

Answer (score 8):

Using a [`GroupAdjacent`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx) extension, you can do:

```
var hasThreeConsecutiveCorrect 
    = myList.GroupAdjacent(item => item.Correct)
            .Any(group => group.Key && group.Count() >= 3);
```

Here's another way with a [`Rollup`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/02/15/rollup-extension-method-create-running-totals-using-linq-to-objects.aspx) extension (a cross between Select and Aggregate) that's somewhat more space-efficient:

```
var hasThreeConsecutiveCorrect 
    = myList.Rollup(0, (item, sum) => item.Correct ? (sum + 1) : 0)
            .Contains(3);
```

Comment: It is also possible without extensions.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov: Sure. Actually, I upvoted yours (it's similar to the Rollup sample I've used), but the key disadvantage is that using Aggregate means we must necessarily consume the entire sequence, which isn't the case with Rollup.

Comment: Yes, Aggregate can be slower.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**:

```
myList.Aggregate(0,
    (result, x) => (result >= 3) ? result : (x.Correct ? result + 1 : 0),
    result => result >= 3);
```

**Generalized version**:

```
myList.Aggregate(0,
    (result, x) => (result >= length) ? result : (filter(x) ? result + 1 : 0),
    result => result >= length);
```

Comment: That's a clever use of `Aggregate`!  I like it.

Comment: @recursive I disagree.  The idea of `Aggregate` is that each item in the sequence represents a portion of a result and that they need to be combined into one item.  This isn't doing that and as such is acting contrary to the design of the method, this creates confusion and hampers readability as it's not using `Aggregate` to aggregate data, it's just using `Aggregate` instead of a `foreach` because `Aggregate` has an internal `foreach` and an outer variable it can piggy back on.  It would be equally effective, and more readable, to just use that `foreach` explicitly.

Comment: @Servy: I understand your point, but it seems arguable.  The case could be made that the run length *is* a result calculated from each of the sequence elements.  The thing that bothers me most about this is its eager consumption of the sequence.

Comment: @recursive The concepts of either clearing the aggregate value or "being done already", each of which are one of the two `if` checks in this code, are contrary to the idea of an aggregate.  An aggregate should also be able to work correctly regardless of the order of the items, that this relies on the order is again contrary to the concept of an aggregate.  It even saves so very little over just using a `foreach`, and loses so much in terms of readability and sensibility to save those few characters; it's totally not worth it.